# How to get out offline player from The End in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-spigot

Hi guys I have problem with my Minecraft server.
I have player in End dimension that causes crashes when he joins the server.
`ReportedException: Colliding entity with block`
Is there any way I can move him from End to Overworld without him dying and losing EQ?

Spigot 1.16.1

Answer (score 2):

The server creates a player data file for every player on the server (in **server dir/world/playerdata**). These files contain data such as the position, dimension, inventory, etc. of a player. The filename is the player's UUID.

You can edit the player's data file using NBTExplorer (which is a free piece of software that can read and modify NBT data). To do this:

- Stop the server
- Make a backup of the player's data file!
- Open the data file in NBTExplorer (not the backup, but the file in the playerdata dir)
- Set the **Dimension** tag to "minecraft:the_overworld"
- Set the **Pos** tag values to where you want to move the player to
- Save the changes
- Start the server